# How to Generate Correct GeoJSON and TopoJSON file for Uganda

Tags: maps, geojson, topojson

I have followed all several instructions on the internet but not results for a while now , i would like to explore D3 for choropleth maps, the topojson being generated cannot be rendered in the browser using d3 am stack at this point,

so far , i have downloaded and installed ogr2ogr , Nodejs

the commands am running to generate the topo json are

ogr2ogr  -f GeoJSON -s_srs EPSG:4199 -t_srs EPSG:4199 districts.json "uganda distriscts.shp"

followed by

topojson --id-property district_i -p district=DIST_2010 -p AREA -p HECTAREAS -o ug.json  districts.json

Am totally New to D3 and TopoJSON and Not a GIS expert either. Please help me get over this huddle attached are the shapefiles i would like to generate topojson and render this on a choropleth map using d3 . i will be glad if any one could provide me with pointers on how to generate the correct topojson formats for uganda since most examples are with USA and other regions. your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Have you used Mike Bostock's tutorial? http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/ I used that to make a shape map of the British isles.  I had to do a bit of lateral thinking about loading the JSON from MVC, but it wasn't too taxing.

Comment: @RobLyndon Mikes tutorial has been very helpful to this point , i guess my issues are stemming from the shapefiles them selves , if that is the case then how can one correct the shapefile before generating the geojson and topojson

Comment: Do you **have to** use your shapefile ? I made a similar work with NaturalEarh's, France (L0), and French regions, together with the makefile and d3js code. Easily portable to Uganda.

Answer (score 2):

First - what is `"uganda distriscts.shp"`? Why you have space in filename and quotes in command. You should have all files without spaces like `uganda_distriscts.shp` or `ugandaDistriscts.shp`, and no need in quotes!

Second - You should convert your map to WGS84 like so:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -s_srs uganda_distriscts.prj -t_srs EPSG:4326 uganda_distriscts_wgs84.json uganda_distriscts.shp
```

Here `uganda_distriscts.prj` is projection file you should have, maybe it has another name, so look in folder for file with extension `.prj`.

Next you should create TopoJSON file like this:

```
topojson -o ug.json --id-property district_i -p district=DIST_2010 -p AREA -p HECTAREAS uganda=uganda_distriscts_wgs84.json
```

And examine this thread [Map with d3.js and TopoJSON, Albers Siberia projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083999/map-with-d3-js-and-topojson-albers-siberia-projection). I hope this will help you.

Comment: KoGor i do not have a .prj file , so far the i can generate the geojson and topojson , however the generate json files do not render correctly using d3. the shape files am a tempting to convert to valid geojson can be found here https://github.com/royowor/uganda-shapefiles.git

Comment: Ok, try this command: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:4326 uganda_distriscts_wgs84.json uganda_distriscts.shp`.
You can read here about params for [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).