# Using D3 to transform NZTM2000 coordinates to WGS84

Tags: javascript, map-projections

I've been trying to convert some NZTM2000, a variaton of the Transverse Mercator projection used in New Zealand (http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/datums-projections-and-heights/projections/new-zealand-transverse-mercator-2000) to WSG84 lattitude/longitude coordinates without success.

The NZTM2000 specs says the TM is configured with the following parameters:

- Origin latitude: ° 00' 00" South
- Origin longitude / central meridan:173° 00' 00" East
- False Northing:10,000,000 metres North
- False Easting:1,600,000 metres East
- Central meridian scale factor:0.9996

I tried to use them in S3:

```
var projection = d3.geo.transverseMercator()
    .rotate([origin_lat, origin_lng])
    .scale(scale_factor)
    .center([false_northing, false_esting])
```

(among other ways).

I was using an small data subset with known WGS84 values:

```
NZTM2000                WSG84
---------------------   -------------------------------
Norting     Easting     Latitude        Longitude
5771280.5   1900560.5   38 09 22.691 S  176 25 48.538 E
5771280.5   1900570.5   38 09 22.679 S  176 25 48.948 E
5771280.5   1900571.5   38 09 22.678 S  176 25 48.989 E
5771280.5   1900572.5   38 09 22.677 S  176 25 49.030 E
```

Any help?

Thank you so much

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16087887/4235784) to a similar question might help.

Comment: Thanks! I'll read the post and examples posted there and write back here my conclussions.

Comment: This looks like a question that may fare better if deleted from here and is re-asked at [gis.se] (it is too old to migrate).

Comment: @rgrocha I have a question, based on the example above what values did you chose for false_northing and false_easting? Did you convert metres to something?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution LINZ site. They have already the algorithm coded in C at http://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-services/download-geodetic-software#nztm2000.

And then again, someone ported it to C# at https://github.com/leighghunt/nztm/blob/master/nztm/nztm.cs.

I ported this latest version to JavaScript and it worked just fine.

Send me a message if you want my version.

=========
can you share the Javascript version in github please? i really need it

Comment: Any reason you don't just include the JavaScript port in the answer?

Comment: it's a long file. I'll updload it to github later today

Comment: Sorry for the (long) delay. It's, finally, at https://github.com/rgrocha/nztm2000js